# android: how to save an image in a object

Tags: android, object, image

What i want is that i have made a picture chooser, the image chosen i then want to save in my own object.

Like i have a class called personalFile, this file then includes all details, name, birthdate etc.. I have made it so i can update this personal file and save them to the external storage getExternalFilesDir() using an ObjectOutPutStream.

Now i have taken a picture of the person, and have browsed my way to the picture and gotten the uri path to the picture, now how do I save this file together with the rest of the information in my class?

I have tried looking but havnt found anyone doing this. The reason is also i'd like to be able to send the personal record to another phone using mms, email or alike and be able to open it there with the picture and all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way of doing it (albeit not the most efficient) would be to have a `byte[] image;` member variable in your class and read the content of your file into that byte array. You are quite likely to experience issues though if the image size is large.  The other alternative would be to just copy the image file to your external storage and inside your class simply save the file name of the file.  Either way, I'm not sure of the merit of saving images as part of your persistent app data (unless the images are really small).

Comment: Ok thanks, that sounds like the files will get immensely big then, better not do it :-)